# Select data from SQL which has not localization

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have three tables, table "local", table item and table "item_local". Here is data contains in the tables:

```
Table "local"
    ID  Local
    1   Ru
    2   En

Table "item"
    ID  Name
    1   Test1
    2   Test2
    3   Test3

Table "item_local"  
    ID  ItemID  LocalID Text
    1   1       1       Test-Ru
    2   1       2       Test-En
    3   2       1       Test-Ru
    4   2       2       Test-En
    5   3       1       Test-Ru
```

My problem is I don't know the SELECT query with local that will display the result such as below:

```
Result if i select with local "Ru":
    ID  ItemID  LocalID Text
    1   1       1       Test-Ru 
    3   2       1       Test-Ru 
    5   3       1       Test-Ru

Result if i select with local "En": 
    ID  ItemID  LocalID Text
    2   1       2       Test-En
    4   2       2       Test-En
    5   3       1       Test-Ru
```

Is there a query or any other way to get such the result?

Anyway, thanks for helping.

Comment: Can there be more than two languages? What should happen if there is no Ru and no En but there is a De?

Comment: You want Test-Ru as well when local is En?

Comment: @Juniad I want get data if it does not have "En" then get "Ru" otherwise En instead of Ru

Comment: @MarkByers Yes there are might be more then two languages.

Comment: So, if there are more than two languages and there is no "En" record..  then what?  Prefer "Dk" over "Ru"?  Or the other way around?  You will need to create a table of language priorities so that the application can know the order in which to fall-back if there is no match.

Comment: @eggyal You are right regarding table for language priorities but in this case i need to get item which comes first.

Comment: MySQL doesn't preserve any notion of table "order", so "first" is meaningless unless you specify an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Miro: What do you mean by "first"? What should happen if there is no "En" and no "Ru" but there is a "De" and "Dk"? Which of those should be chosen? How do I know which is "first"? First what? First in alphabetical order or what? I have to agree with eggyat: a table with language priorities seems the way to go here.

Comment: @MarkByers I mean by the "first" any item which has any localization

Comment: @Miro: So let me see if I understand you... if the client asks for "Ru" then if you can find "Ru" then you want to fetch that. If you can't find the language the user wants, fetch any one of the others with no particular preference, and in an extreme case it could even choose a different language for each missing text. Right? If so, it has nothing to do with "first". Using the word "any" is better. "First" implies an ordering.

Comment: @MarkByers Yes, you understood me right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT il.ID, il.ItemID, il.LocalID, il.Text
FROM item i
JOIN local l ON l.Local='Ru'
[LEFT] JOIN item_local il ON i.ID=il.ItemID AND il.LocalID=l.ID
```

Note that the table `item` is not necessary. However, I guess you would like to see the missing entries in the step. This can be done by using the `LEFT JOIN` and add the condition `WHERE il.ID IS NULL`.

**Edit:** Oh, is missed the fallback to "Ru".

```
-- try 'En'
SELECT il.ID, il.ItemID, il.LocalID, il.Text
FROM item_local il
JOIN local l ON l.Local='En' AND l.ID=il.LocalID
UNION
-- fallback to 'Ru'
SELECT il.ID, il.ItemID, il.LocalID, il.Text
FROM item_local il
JOIN local l ON l.Local='Ru' AND l.ID=il.LocalID
WHERE il.ItemID NOT IN (
    SELECT il.ItemID
    FROM item_local il
    JOIN local l ON l.Local='En' AND l.ID=il.LocalID
)
```

Comment: thank you. it works, but you need change query in the "where" condition from `SELECT il.ID
    FROM item_local il
    JOIN local l ON l.Local='En' AND l.ID=il.LocalID` to `SELECT il.ItemID
    FROM item_local il
    JOIN local l ON l.Local='En' AND l.ID=il.LocalID`. Is it possible do this query more common without hard coding?

Comment: @Miro: Thanks, fixed the SQL statement. What do you mean with without hard coding? Of course, you can replace the literals with SQL variables, or use placeholders in prepared statements.